# C# datagridview editing control

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an application that has a datagridview in it obviously enough, and I add data to it programatically like so:

```
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(string[]);
```

Before I add any objects to the dataGridView I can edit the cells by double clicking, hitting enter or f2. After data has been added into the rows however, I can no longer edit any of the values. I have tried toggling the "Read Only" attribute from true to false, and also tried to mess with:

```
    dataGridview1.EditMode ....
```

I don't know how to make the edit mode work properly, but on all previous keystrokes it just highlights the next row in the list.

How can I enable the user to edit the data in the data grid view once the rows have been added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a list of tutorials on ways to accomplish this here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/433279/edit-delete-update-cancel-in-gridview-asp-net

I would start with these.